Non-periodic motion in systems of 2 DOF
I was learning the vibrations of systems of 2 DOF.
One of the most simple examples is the following system:

Since it is a system of 2 DOF, it has 2 natural frequencies $\omega_{n1}$ and $\omega_{n2}$; $\omega_{n1} < \omega_{n2}$ .
I heard that when the ratio of the natural frequencies is a whole number, the motion is periodic, but when that same ratio is not an integer, the motion is non-periodic, i.e.
$$\frac{\omega_{n2}}{\omega_{n1}} \in \mathbb{Z} \Rightarrow periodic \space motion$$
$$\frac{\omega_{n2}}{\omega_{n1}} \notin \mathbb{Z} \Rightarrow non-periodic \space motion$$
How can that be? Non-periodic motion seems like a really complex phenomenon being exhibited by such a simple system consisting of only 2 masses and some springs.
Is that true? And if so, is than the motion chaotic or random or something else?

what is the period of $a(t)=\sin(2\pi t) +\sin(2\pi\sqrt{2}t)$?

This question was answered here. Check the answer and the references therein

Chaos and nonlinear dynamics is a rich and deep field of study.  However, some aspects of it like aperiodocity can be understood quite intuitively, as you yourself are describing.  For the motion to be described as "chaotic" it needs to meet other criteria as well, including non-noisy input and sensitive dependence on initial conditions.

I you were to plot a configuration space diagram, with $x_1$ and $x_2$ in the x and y axis, then periodic motion only means that the curve loops back at itself at some point in the future (the period). For a non-periodic system, the only difference is that the curve will never loop back on itself. It says nothing about smoothness or chaos for a system.
Here is an example with the solution
$$\pmatrix{x_1 \\ x_2 } = \pmatrix{ \cos(t) +\sin(3 t) \\ \sin(t) -\cos(3 t) } $$
configuration space plot

But with the solution of
$$\pmatrix{x_1 \\ x_2 } = \pmatrix{ \cos(t) +\sin(\pi t) \\ \sin(t) -\cos(\pi t) } $$
configuration space plot

The curve doesn't quite come back to itself ever, even though the curve itself is smooth and "predictable".
here is the same result but for $t=0 \ldots 100$

and at $t=100$ the point is just hanging out in space, a slight difference away from prior curves. Now you can run this to $t=10^{80} \ll \infty$ and there will be continually new ground the end point will cover until it fills the entire kinematic envelope (the circle with radius 2) with infinite points.

Wow, a really nice answer. I did not know that. Thank you.

In what program did you plot the graphs? I would like to play around with it.

What functions of x1 and x2 will exhibit chaotic motion? If you happed to know any examples

@User198 responding to your 3rd comment. So we know a small amplitude pendulum has the same equation of motion (EOM) as a mass/spring system. And we know a double pendulum is chaotic. If you delete the right spring, then you have the double pendulum--in the small angle approximation. It's possible the linear response of the ideal spring ruins chaos? In the double pendulum, you're way past the small angle approximation, and have seriously diverging trajectories around $\theta_2=\pi$. So idk, but it's something to think about.

@User198 - the graphs were copied from Wolfram Alpha
